# Setting UILabel before adding Subview in UIWindow fails

Tags: objective-c, iphone

The property **label** is of type **UILabel** and is an outlet in **UIViewController**.

Why does the following work :-

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController.label setText:@"New Label"] ;
```

and the reverse sequence of statements doesn't change the default text in the label:

```
[viewController.label setText:@"New Label"] ;
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Isn't view loaded from the UI elements attached to the UIViewController ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view controller creates or loads its view when it's first requested, either from a NIB or via the `loadView` method.  And in most cases, the associated subviews are also only created when the main view is loaded.  That means that `viewController.label` is `nil` until you've first tried to access `viewController.view`.

So if you try to set the label text first, you're actually just sending that message to `nil`, which is why it doesn't appear to have taken effect.